# What is cause my downloaded file to be inauthentic?

Tags: python, c++, build, eigen

I've been trying to install this ATLAS tool on my windows computer. The instructions are very simple and straight forward:

clone the ATLAS git repository:

```
$ git clone https://gitlab.inria.fr/alta/alta.git
```

I should have all the mandatory dependencies installed:

- the SCons build system;
- a C++11 compiler, such as recent versions of GCC or Clang;
- Eigen >= 3.0 (libeigen3-dev package on Debian and derivatives; libeigen3 in MacPorts; eigen in Brew.)

Essentially, after I have those installed, I can run scons on python and it should check to see whether the required dependencies are met, and then all compilation byproducts will go to the sources/build like the instructions says. The problem is after running the scons command, I get the following response:

```
    scons: Reading SConscript files ...
    <<INFO>> Using config file "./configs/scons/config-windows-cl.py"
    the current platform is: win32
    Checking for C++ library dl... no
    Checking for C++ library rt... no
    Checking whether 'c++11' is supported... yes
    Checking for eigen3 using pkg-config... no
    Checking for C++ header file Eigen/Core... no
    obtaining Eigen v3.2.7
    error: downloaded file 'eigen-3.2.7.tar.gz' is inauthentic
    error: got sha256 hash ea25f177c8716e7daa618533e116706d97e25c9912e016009d8a9264e39cad57 but expected 5a50a006f83480a31f1f9beabec9e91dad95138df19363ee73ccf57676f10405
    eigen-3.2.7.tar.gz: downloaded file is inauthentic
```

The compilation process results in a `eigen-3.2.7.tar.gz` file with a `WRONG-HASH File` type. Moreover, when I open the file, it reads, *"Repository eigen/eigen not found"*.

What does it mean that the `eigen-3.2.7.tar.gz` file is inauthentic and why does it have a `WRONG-HASH File` type? My guess is that my machine is complaining that the eigen repository is not downloaded, but I thought I installed everything correctly.
Here how I went about installing the dependencies:

**Scons**

I installed Scons build system by simply typing the following command in my anaconda python environment:

```
conda install -c conda-forge scons
```

**C++ complier**

This was actually already installed on my computer a while back ago. I can't exactly remember how it was installed, but my machine seems to recognize it on the checklist so no need to worry about that.

**Eigen**
To install this dependency I just simply cloned the repository from [here](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen) in GitHub. The Eigen folder is find inside the alta directory(the highest level directory).

I am new on this, so it could be very possible that my steps to install these dependencies were not correct. Should I set some sort of environment path? I'm wondering if I installed my eigen repository correctly. To be honest, I'm not exactly sure why the build process fail, thus the issue may be something totally different then how I installed my dependencies. However, at this point I am lost and in need of further instruction or intuition.

The link to the installation page is [here](http://alta.gforge.inria.fr/install.html) . As you can see its not many instruction and they are quite simple, which makes this whole thing even more frustrating.

Comment: When you do a package you share it sha to validate that the one you get is the expected one. Here you get `eigen-3.2.7.tar.gz` but without the good signature, if you trust the file you can force but this can be a malicious package. More details here https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/189000/how-to-verify-the-checksum-of-a-downloaded-file-pgp-sha-etc

Comment: The link to Eigen in the ALTA source code no longer works, that is why it errors, you should consider that this project has no commits for over two years.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Thank you for commenting. How do you know it no longer works? Could it be because I'm using a newer version of scons? How do you know that it no longer works anymore?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do what you do, if you check the URL in https://gitlab.inria.fr/alta/alta/-/blob/master/external/obtain_eigen.py and open it with a browser you get a 404 error, eigen is no longer hosted in bitbucket but now in gitlab, you can even see that in the eigen website: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page